# android-graphview - set values dynamically

Tags: android, android-graphview

So I am using android-graphview (https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView).

I'm trying to figure out how to add `DataPoints` to the series programmatically one by one as i fetch data from source.

Currently the doc says to do:

```
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series2 = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
    new DataPoint(0, 4),
    new DataPoint(1, 5),
    new DataPoint(2, 2),
    new DataPoint(3, 1),
    new DataPoint(4, 10)
});
```

But i want to be able to add/create dynamically as my for loop gets those data points.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to append data to an existing series, that was added to the graph.

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.gv);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> lineGraphSeries = new LineGraphSeries<>();

graph.addSeries(lineGraphSeries);

DataPoint dataPoint = sth...
lineGraphSeries.appendData(dataPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AddSeriesAtRuntime extends BaseExample {
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(FullscreenActivity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        GraphView graph = (GraphView) activity.findViewById(R.id.graph);
        initGraph(graph);
    }

    @Override
    public void initGraph(final GraphView graph) {
        Button btn = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnAddSeries);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                graph.addSeries(new LineGraphSeries(generateData()));
            }

        });

        btn = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                graph.removeAllSeries();
            }
        });
    }

    private DataPoint[] generateData() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int count = 30;
        DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[count];
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            double x = i;
            double f = rand.nextDouble()*0.15+0.3;
            double y = Math.sin(i*f+2) + rand.nextDouble()*0.3;
            DataPoint v = new DataPoint(x, y);
            values[i] = v;
        }
        return values;
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphview_demos/examples/AddSeriesAtRuntime.java